# ember.js custom component or view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm attempting to create a reusable typeahead component(?) for my app. I'm using [twitter's typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) javascript library and trying to create a custom component/view out of it.

I would like to be able to define the typeahead in my templates like so:

```
{{view App.TypeAhead name=ta_name1 prefretch=prefetch1 template=template1 valueHolder=ta_value1}}
```

I was thinking those variables would be located in the controllers:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  ta_name1: 'movies',

  prefetch1: '../js/stubs/post_1960.json',

  template1: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> - {{year}}</p>',

  ta_value1: null    
});
```

I don't know what i need to use to accomplish this, a component or a view. I would imagine it would *something* like this.

```
App.Typeahead = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'typeahead',
  didInsertElement: function() {

    $('.typeahead').typeahead([{
      name: this.getName(),
      prefetch: this.getPrefetch(),
      template: this.getTemplate(),
      engine: Hogan,
      limit: 10
    }]);

    $('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function(datum) {
        this.set('controllers.current.' + this.getValueHolder()), datum);
    });
  }
});
```

With a template like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='typeahead'>
    <input class="typeahead" type="text">
</script>
```

I don't know how to get away from the jQuery class selector. In reality, i will have more than one typeahead on a form so this class selection isn't going to cut it.

I also don't know how to get the values from the controller in the View. Obviously the `getPrefetch()`, `getTemplate()`, `getValueHolder()`, etc methods don't exist.

I know this is a TON of pseudo code but hopefully i can get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my [Twitter TypeAhead implementation for Ember](https://github.com/pjlammertyn/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/packages/ember-bootstrap/lib/views/type_ahead.js).

you can use it like this:

```
APP.CardiologistsTypeAhead = Bootstrap.Forms.TypeAhead.extend({
  dataset_limit: 10,
  dataset_valueKey: 'id',
  dataset_engine: Bootstrap.TypeAhead.HandlebarsEngine.create(),
  dataset_template: '<strong>{{lastName}} {{firstName}}</strong>',
  dataset_remote: {
    url: '%QUERY',
    override: function (query, done) {
        $.connection.cardiologists.server.getAllByLastNameLike(query) //SignalR
        .then(function (cariologists) {
            done(cariologists);
        });
    }
  },

  didInsertElement: function () {
    this._super();

    var self = this;
    Em.run.schedule('actions', this, function () {
        var cardiologistFullName = this.get('controller.content.cardiologistFullName');
        self.get('childViews')[1].$().val(cardiologistFullName);
    });
  },

  valueChanged: function () {
    this._super();

    this.get('childViews')[1].$().typeahead('setQuery', this.get('controller.content.cardiologistFullName'));
  }.observes('value'),

  selected: function (cardiologist) {
    var cardiologistFullName = '%@ %@'.fmt(Em.get(cardiologist, 'lastName'), Em.get(cardiologist, 'firstName'));
    this.set('controller.content.cardiologistFullName', cardiologistFullName);
    this.set('value', Em.get(cardiologist, 'id'));
  }
});
```

and the handlebars:

```
{{view APP.CardiologistsTypeAhead
classNames="col-sm-6"
label="Cardiologist:"
valueBinding="controller.content.referrerCardiologist"}}
```

Comment: awesome project! bookmarked. I will definitely have a look through your implementation. thanks a ton!

Comment: Not sure this answer actually answer your question. It only gives you a solution for your means, but there's nothing about how fixing your problem with Ember....

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a component for this.

The secret afterwards is that Ember components (and View) expose a `this.$` function which is a jQuery selector scoped to the current view. So you only need to do this:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$(".typeahead"); // ... etc
}
```

Comment: ahhhh that's the missing link. appreciate it.